# Error in loading ROOT output graph in LaTex file

Tags: graphics, import, root

I was trying to insert the graph created using ROOT in my LaTex file as per this [webpage](https://root.cern.ch/content/saving-canvas-tex) . It tells to save the ROOT output graph in tex and then embed it in the LaTex File. But when I am trying to save my ROOT file in Tex, there is this error:

[image]

I load the ROOT file using `.x qcd.C` and then use the File button to "Save as 'c4.tex' ". That's when it gives the error.

What should I do?

P.S. Is there any other procedure to get my ROOT output embedded to the LaTex file? I want the file to contain the graph when opened or printed.

Comment: Have you installed Postscript (maybe with some libraries)? The error says it cannot find it.

Comment: Sorry, but this seems to be all on ROOT's side and that TeX and friends are not involved in any way.